# Vuex store is inaccessible

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I made a vuex store:

```
export const general = {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        menuEnabled: true,
        headerEnabled: true
    },
    getters: {
        menuState: state => state.menuEnabled,
        headerState: state => state.headerEnabled
    },
    actions: {
        setMenuVisibility({commit}, visibility) {
            commit('setMenuVisibility', visibility);
        },
        setHeaderVisibility({commit}, visibility) {
            commit('setHeaderVisibility', visibility);
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        setMenuVisibility(state, visibility){
            state.menuEnabled = visibility;
        },
        setHeaderVisibility(state, visibility){
            state.headerEnabled = visibility;
        }
    }
}
```

**index.js**

```
import { createStore } from "vuex";
import { auth } from "./auth.module";
import {general} from "./general.module";

const store = createStore({
    modules: {
        general,
        auth
    },
});
export default store;
```

**main.js**

```
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";

createApp(App)
    .use(store)
    .use(router)
    .mount('#app')
```

After that, I created 2 `computed` functions in `App.vue`:

```
computed: {
    menuVisibilityState : function (){
      return this.$store.state.menuEnabled;
    },
    headersVisibilityState : function () {
      return this.$store.state.headerEnabled;
    }
  }
```

But, I can't get them from `vuex`:
[image]

I tried to import `general` directly in `App.vue` and get the values.
It doesn't work and I think, that it's bad way to get them.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a module in Vuex, the *local state* is nested depending on the name you've provided to the module (this happens when you're accessing the root state.).

In your example, to access the local state of *general* module you could write:

```js
computed: {
    menuVisibilityState : function (){
      return this.$store.state.general.menuEnabled;
    },
    headersVisibilityState : function () {
      return this.$store.state.general.headerEnabled;
    }
  }
```

Keep in mind that:

> actions and mutations are still registered under the global namespace - this allows multiple modules to react to the same action/mutation type. Getters are also registered in the global namespace by default.
> https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing